# Nexus 2.14.4-03 installed but login fail with admin/admin123

Tags: authentication, repository, admin, nexus, sonatype

I installed nexus repository but login failed , I tried a lot of things in support site of nexus and some stack overflow replies against questions.At the below , error screen I copied.
Anyone help please ? Thank you so much..

[UI/Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nElNa.png)

Comment: Check the nexus.log file from the install, I suspect it didn't start, and there was already a nexus running on that port.

Comment: I executed "nexus install" , then "nexus start" commands at the ..bin/ directory and checked port usage , but anymore usage of 8081 ,only nexus

Comment: anyone help pls ? Still failed login..

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out exact steps to reproduce. For clarities sake, can you post what system you are using, if you were using an older version of Nexus Repository prior and upgraded it, and any other steps?

Comment: win10 , 64 bit system , jdk32/64 , 1.8.131 version both installed , nexus 2.14.4-03 version and 32-64 bit nexus installation all tried from directory ../bin/jsw/ . Nexus install and start , and ı can see UI of Nexus at localhos:8081/nexus , but login failed

Comment: If it's a clean install then you've corrupted it somehow, the default login is always admin/admin123.  If it's an upgrade and you forgot your password see here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465508

Comment: I just downloaded then extracted folder then run 'nexus install' and 'nexus start' commands.When I checked in browser , ı could not login.Just what I did